# Proxy rtp source stream to rtsp via live555

Tags: stream, streaming, rtsp, rtp, live555

I have a RTP stream which generated by ffmepg, now I need to restream to RTSP with [live555](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/).

There is a way to restream from a RTSP to another RTSP: [LIVE555 Proxy Server](http://www.live555.com/proxyServer/).

But how to modify the Proxy Server to restream RTP source to RTSP (I can get the sdp description) ?

i.e.

- source stream: rtp://192.168.1.10:55555
- retream to: rtsp://:554/stream1

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I find the solution.

Inherit the `OnDemandServerMediaSubsession` class, use the `MPEG4ESVideoRTPSource` and 'MPEG4VideoStreamDiscreteFramer' to get RTP input.

Then make a little change from `DynamicRTSPServer` by replacing `createNewSMS` function.

This RTP proxier got working!

Comment: I am sending H.264 video in MPEGTS format to rtp://xx.xx.xx.xx:abcd

Comment: Which RTP source and framer should I use?

Comment: I am a new developer for live555, can you show the sample code for OnDemandServerMediaSubsession.

Comment: First need create Groupsock and bind to special port and pass Groupsock to MPEG4ESVideoRTPSource as createNewStreamSource return value;  what does MPEG4VideoStreamDiscreteFramer mean?